# Xamarin deploy error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, target-framework

I'm trying to open [this](https://github.com/brminnick/InvestmentDataSampleApp) app on my Sony ST23i(Android 4.0.3-API 15). So i changed "Minimum Android to Target" to "Android 4.0.3 API Level 15" from "Android 4.3 API Level 18". But now i get these errors when i try to deploy the app.

```
    The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll (v7.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project. 

The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (v7.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.

The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll (v7.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
```

I can't increase TargetFrameworkVersion from the csproj file it returns back to 6. How can i run this app on my phone?

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns back to 6"? Could you give some detailed steps of how you change the "$(TargetFrameworkVersion)" and by what steps it returns back to 6?

Comment: In android's csproj file this line exists.

<TargetFrameworkVersion>v6.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>

I changed it to this.

<TargetFrameworkVersion>v7.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>

But when i open the project with visual studio it turns back to 6.0

Answer (score 0):

> In android's csproj file this line exists.
>   `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v6.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` I changed it to this. `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v7.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` But when i open the project with visual studio it turns back to 6.0

You can change the `TargetFrameworkVersion` by following two steps:

1. Right-click your project->properties->Application Tab.
2. Change "Compile using Android Version(Target Framework)" to Android 7.0.